# ¿Que es stdcall y para que se usa?

Tags: c++, c, windows

He buscando información en la pagina oficial de microsoft y tengo entendido que se usa para las llamadas a funciones y limpiar el stack de la pila si no me equivoco pero ¿Que beneficio tiene esto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> He buscando información en la pagina oficial de Microsoft y tengo entendido que se usa para las llamadas a funciones y limpiar el stack de la pila si no me equivoco.

No te equivocas, pero te has quedado con la forma sin llegar al fondo:

> #### [`__stdcall`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/cpp/stdcall)
>
> La convención de llamada `__stdcall` se usa para llamar a funciones de la API de Win32.

La página oficial indica que se trata de una **convención de llamada**, las convenciones de llamada nos indican:

- El orden en que los parámetros se alojan en memoria.
- Cómo se pasan los parámetros (¿se apilan?, ¿se pasan en [registros](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Registro_(hardware))?).
- Qué registros debe preservar la función para que sean usados por el llamador.
- De qué manera se reparten el llamador y el llamado la tarea de preparar y restablecer la pila.

Las implementaciones de esos puntos pueden variar mucho entre convenciones de llamada dando lugar a muchas convenciones diferentes e incompatibles incluso entre compiladores; por eso (en general) para seguir un modelo estándar, se aplican determinadas convenciones de llamada en las funciones que se publican en APIs o librerías.

En el caso de los compiladores de Microsoft, la convención de llamada predeterminada es `__stdcall`, pero existen otras convenciones:

- [`__cdecl`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/cpp/cdecl).
- [`__fastcall`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/cpp/fastcall).
- [`__thiscall`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/cpp/thiscall).
- [`__vectorcall`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/cpp/cpp/vectorcall).